# Is this a good Java gameloop?

Tags: java, game-loop

I wonder if this gameloop in Java is accurate to give around 60 frames a second, is it?

```
public void run() {
    long then = System.nanoTime();
    long targetFPS = 60;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - then;
        long update = updateLength / targetFPS;
        then = now;
        System.out.println(update);
        if(update >= 16){
            render();
            tick();
            System.out.println(updateLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Measure it (filler)

Comment: Also do you not generally tick then render?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.

This keeps the CPU running constantly, which uses a lot of power. Also, system.nanotime can be really slow on certain PCs. Instead try something like:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Do your stuff
Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, time - 16));
run();
```

This doesn't exactly produce 60 fps, because that requires 16,66 milliseconds between frames, but it's really close.